# left joining and combining the results where they are not null

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.6, null

I'm given a MySQL database with tables like this:

```
show create table c;
CREATE TABLE `c` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- and other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
show create table c_r;
CREATE TABLE `c_r` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `something_numeric` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- and other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`)
)
show create table c_s;
CREATE TABLE `c_s` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_date` date DEFAULT NULL
  `something_numeric` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- and other columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`)
)
```

Now, I want, for each `date`, the sum of the `something_numeric` values from `c_r` and the sum of the `something_numeric` values from `c_s`. If one of those is null, I still want the other. My output should have a row per `date`.

I don't see a way to get that. If I `join` twice on `c.id`, I get only such dates as exist in both `c_r` and `c_s`; so I need to `left join` twice instead. But then how do I make sure to get one row per `date` altogether, whether that `date` exists in only one table, only the other, or both?

Comment: Looks like the [`IFNULL()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) is what you need.

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to be: `date, sum(c_r.something_numeric), sum(c_s.something_numeric)` or `date, sum(something_numeric)`?

Comment: The former, @Marco.

Comment: @mustaccio, something like `select ifnull(c_r.date,c_s.date), sum(c_r.something_numeric), sum(c_s.something.numeric) from c left join c_r on c_r.c_id=c.id left join c_s on c_s.c_id=c.id`? That'll get the wrong data for dates where one of the dates is null. I want the `c_r.something_numeric` output to be empty where `c_r.date` is null. If you meant something else, please clarify (presumably in an answer post).

Comment: Your question states: "_If one of those [something_numeric] is null, I still want the other_"; why do you then use dates in the `NULLIF()` call?

Comment: @mustaccio, I don't understand your last comment. I don't have a `nullif` call.

Comment: Could you add your expected results to the question? I'm not sure if you're looking for sums of `c_r` and `c_s` numbers by date, or by `c.id` by date. Also - are they any rows in `c_r` and `c_s` that won't match any rows in `c`?

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, it was a typo. I meant to say `IFNULL()` of course, because that's what we were discussing.

Comment: @mustaccio, I don't have `ifnull` either. You do, in your comment. I mentioned it only in an effort to understand your comment, and guessed you meant to `ifnull` the dates. If that's not what you meant, then please explain what you did mean.

Comment: @RDFozz, I want to group by date only. I'm on mobile now so cannot easily edit the post to clarify that or, especially, to include example output, but I plan to do so when I can. No rows in `c_*` **should** fail to match `c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an actual query attempt from you, some thing are difficult to understand.

From what you've said, you're looking to group by date only, not on any information from `c`. That being the case, it's not clear that `c` needs to be in the query at all.

The following query should give you the totals you want, for all dates found in either `c_r` or `c_s`:

```
SELECT c_date
      ,COALESCE(SUM(r_amount),0) as r_amount
      ,COALESCE(SUM(s_amount),0) as s_amount
  FROM (
        SELECT c_date, 0 as r_amount, something_numeric as s_amount
          FROM c_s
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c_date, something_numeric as r_amount, 0 as s_amount
          FROM c_r
       ) sq
 GROUP BY c_date
;
```

If you need to limit rows by some value in `c`, `INNER JOIN` each of the tables in the subquery to `c` separately, with identical `WHERE` clauses. You could alternately include the values from `c` in the subquery's `SELECT` list, and filter in the main query, but that's probably less efficient.

Comment: +1, looks promising; many thanks; I'll try it when I get back to this next week.